# What does a trailing '==' after a variable assignment do in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables

I recently stumbled across a line of code running on Python 3.7 which I hadn't seen before and couldn't find anything online as I didn't know what to search.

The context is similar to the following:

```
def some_function(some_var: bool = None):

    if some_var is None:
        some_var = os.environ.get("SOME_ENV_VAR", False) == "true"
```

What does the trailing double equals do here and why would it be used?

Comment: It's just a comparison. `some_var` is set to the result of comparing the return value of `get` to the string `"true"`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite this piece of code as the following to see more clearly what it's doing.

```
if some_var is None:
   if os.environ.get("SOME_ENV_VAR", False) == "true":
       some_var = True
   else
       some_var = False
```

This line:

```
os.environ.get("SOME_ENV_VAR", False) == "true"
```

is a conditional check and then `some_var` would be assigned the result of the `True`/`False` check.

Answer (score 0):

There's no exotic syntax here. `==` is just a binary (as in "two arguments") operator, just like `+` or `and`.

You can see the line as `a = b == c`, and just like `a = b + c` would mean "Compute `b + c` and store that in `a`", this means "Compute `b == c` and store that in `a`, ie. put `True` in `a` if `b` is equal to `c`, `False` otherwise.